# docker entrypoint running bash script gets "permission denied" for one docker container but works fine for another container

Tags: python, bash, docker

I have created a simple api application using FastAPI framework.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10.13-slim-bookworm as base

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev gcc

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--reload"]
```

docker-compose.yml file

```yaml
version: "3"
services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    depends_on:
      - api_1
      - api_2
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

  api_1:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: .
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
        - .:/app # This is the line that mounts the local directory to the container
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - "./docker-entrypoint.sh"

  api_2:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: .
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
        - .:/app # This is the line that mounts the local directory to the container
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - "./docker-entrypoint.sh"

  db:
    image: "postgres:16"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: sre-bootcamp
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

I want to create 2 containers of api server and load balance it behind nginx.
So when I do `docker compose up` following are the logs I get

```
Attaching to sre_bootcamp-api_1-1, sre_bootcamp-api_2-1, sre_bootcamp-db-1, sre_bootcamp-nginx-1
sre_bootcamp-db-1     |
sre_bootcamp-db-1     | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
sre_bootcamp-db-1     |
sre_bootcamp-db-1     | 2024-03-11 15:35:25.767 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.2 (Debian 16.2-1.pgdg120+2) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
sre_bootcamp-db-1     | 2024-03-11 15:35:25.767 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
sre_bootcamp-db-1     | 2024-03-11 15:35:25.767 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
sre_bootcamp-db-1     | 2024-03-11 15:35:25.779 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
sre_bootcamp-db-1     | 2024-03-11 15:35:25.788 UTC [28] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-03-11 15:34:53 UTC
sre_bootcamp-db-1     | 2024-03-11 15:35:25.805 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
**sre_bootcamp-api_2-1  | /bin/bash: line 1: ./docker-entrypoint.sh: Permission denied**
sre_bootcamp-api_2-1 exited with code 126
sre_bootcamp-api_1-1  | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
sre_bootcamp-api_1-1  | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
sre_bootcamp-nginx-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
**sre_bootcamp-nginx-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
sre_bootcamp-nginx-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh**
sre_bootcamp-api_1-1  | INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/app']
sre_bootcamp-api_1-1  | INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
sre_bootcamp-api_1-1  | INFO:     Started reloader process [7] using WatchFiles
sre_bootcamp-nginx-1  | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
sre_bootcamp-nginx-1  | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
sre_bootcamp-nginx-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
sre_bootcamp-nginx-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
sre_bootcamp-nginx-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
sre_bootcamp-nginx-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
sre_bootcamp-nginx-1  | 2024/03/11 15:35:33 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "api_2:8000" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:4
sre_bootcamp-nginx-1  | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "api_2:8000" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:4
sre_bootcamp-nginx-1 exited with code 1
sre_bootcamp-api_1-1  | INFO:     Started server process [9]
sre_bootcamp-api_1-1  | INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
sre_bootcamp-api_1-1  | INFO:     Application startup complete.
```

When I do `ls -l docker-entrypoint.sh` it returns `-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant`.

From the above logs, `sre_bootcamp-api_2-1` got exited because of permission but `sre_bootcamp-api_1-1` ran without any issues.

Could someone please help me in understanding, why one container is getting exited because of permission issue and other runs fine?

Comment: There are only so many reasons you can get a "permission denied" (and chmod 777 solves absolutely none of them; don't ever do it). Make sure you have permissions not just to the script itself but to the executable named by its shebang and the libraries used by that executable. Make sure everything involved lives on a well-behaved UNIX filesystem (you can't have executables coming from a network filesystem that doesn't support `mmap()`, or for anything mounted with the `noexec` flag, f/e).

Comment: If you don't _want_ the shebang to be used, then instead of `bash -c ./yourscript` you should just have `bash ./yourscript` -- or, if you _do_ want the shebang to be honored, you're better off replacing `bash -c ./yourscript` with just `./yourscript`; it'll fail pretty much all the same ways, but it'll be less needlessly inefficient while doing it.

Comment: Your `volumes:` and `command:` are overriding what the container normally does, and in particular `volumes:` hiding all of `/app` means you're not really using anything built into the image at all, your behavior is basically totally dependent on what happens to be on the host system.  Does deleting these blocks help at all?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks, your comment helped in resolving the issue. Replaced the command in `docker-compose.yml` file with `command: bash ./docker-entrypoint.sh`. And removed the shebang . I want to learn more about this area. As a beginner, where should I start, do you have any recommendations for building solid foundations?

Comment: There's a lot to cover, so it's hard to pin down a starting point. Personally, I'd call `man 2 execve` worth being familiar with. Also, while it's not quite answering what you asked, the essay (by someone I used to work with) [commandname extensions considered harmful](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/) may be helpful re: understanding why using shebangs (and _not_ using extensions) is considered a Good Idea; for something with more history, https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/ goes into how older UNIXlikes handled shebangs.

Comment: BTW, I'm curious what the shebang on the original script _actually contained_ before you removed it. If it was `#!/usr/bin/env bash` it presumably would have worked just as well as `bash scriptname` would have.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy shebang on `docker-entrypoint.sh` was `#!/bin/bash`. Again thanks for the guidance, will go through the links you shared and man pages.

Comment: Does `command -v bash` inside the container emit `/bin/bash`, or something else? (I wouldn't expect `#!/bin/bash` to be problematic, unless your file had DOS newlines instead of UNIX ones, or you're running on a distro that doesn't keep the `bash` executable in `/bin` -- such distros do exist, [I use one myself](https://nixos.org/) -- but assuming all that's correct, then we're looking at not the content of the shebang but the fact that you were relying on one itself being a problem; meaning a filesystem mounted noexec, or SELinux rules, or such).

Comment: `command -v bash` inside container emits `/usr/bin/bash`. As I am reading about shebang, it makes sense what you say that `#!/bin/bash` won't cause problem. I added back the shebang and it still works. I am on WSL 2 and I am using windows mount drive to run the project. Path of project dir is `/mnt/c/Users/vanshmittal/Desktop/`. Would that be causing any issue?